# elementary OS does not respond after boot

Tags: boot

my problem is that after boot hardly anything in the OS works. I can open applications but I cant do anything with them, they simply don't respond.

I found that after I press power button(hibernate) and then again(wake), the system starts working absolutely perfectly. But hibernating and waking my PC after every boot is pretty annoying.

Anyone has any idea how to solve this?

Comment: I also have this issue. Exactly the same as you describe! You've probably gave up by now, but I would really love to fix this annoying bug..

Comment: Yes. You are right that I gave up. But I read it might have something to do with having internet connection available during the installation of Elementary. So if you want to try at least something, just disable internet connection and reinstall the system.

Please tell me if it worked. I might give Elementary another chance.

Comment: The updates resolved the issue here.